# Why doesn't my cast from enum to int work in release builds?

Tags: c++, casting, enums

I have discovered that the following code works correctly in a debug build, but incorrectly in release:

```
enum FileFormatDetection
{
    Binary,
    ASCII,
    Auto
};

FileFormatDetection detection_mode = (FileFormatDetection)ReadIntKey(NULL, KEY_ALL, "FIL_ASCIIORBINARY", -1); // Assigns -1, as confirmed by debug output
if (detection_mode < 0 || detection_mode > 2)
{
    // Not a valid value, so set to default:
    detection_mode = Auto;
}
```

In each build, debugging output confirmed that the value was -1.  In a debug build, the value -1 caused the if-branch to be entered; in release, it didn't.

I have tried casting detection_mode to an int as follows:

```
if ((int)detection_mode < 0 || (int)detection_mode > 2)
```

and:

```
if (int(detection_mode) < 0 || int(detection_mode) > 2)
```

but neither makes any difference.

The only way I could make this work was to cast the enum variable to an integer stack-variable and test that:

```
int detection_int = (int)detection_mode;
if (detection_int < 0 || detection_int > 2)
{
    ...
```

Now the if-branch is entered, as expected.

I can't understand why this was necessary - I still think the original code (or at least testing the cast temporaries) should have worked.  Can anyone explain why it didn't?

Comment: Could you write error message generated by compiler?

Comment: @Miro as stated within the question, the code does compile - it just does not work as expected.

Comment: Honestly casting -1 to an enum with no specified value for -1 smells like undefined behaviour. I don't know if it is, but it seems like it should be.

Comment: What's this `ReadIntKey()` function? Is this a Windows-specific question?

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that the cast is causing undefined behavior as you are assigning a value that is not one of the enumerators to the enumeration.

When you compile in release mode, the optimizer is seeing the expression:

```
if (detection_mode < 0 || detection_mode > 2)
```

and knows that the type of `detection_mode` is `FileFormatDetection`, it knows that all valid values of that particular enumeration are in range, so the if statement can never be `true` (at least in a well defined program) so it removes the `if` altogether.

Casting to `int` in the `if` will not help, because the same line of reasoning still applies: the value before the cast (again in a well defined program) is in the range `[0..2]` so the optimizer removes the `if`. It is important to note that whether the cast is explicit or not does not really matter, as the enum will be converted to `int` for the comparison in both cases.

If you store the value in an `int` then everything changes. There are quite a few `int` values that fall outside of that range, so the comparison must be performed. Also note that with this change, the program becomes well defined, since `-1` **is** a valid `int`. This is actually what you should be doing: get the value as an `int`, and only if it can be converted to the enum, perform the conversion.

Comment: Well, that sums up my suspicions quite nicely :)

Comment: This sounds reasonable, but I would say that no compiler should ever assume that `enum` contains only valid values

Comment: @Yossarian: Well... Chris has just found one that does :) And as a matter of fact, I would be surprised if most compilers on the most aggressive optimization level did not assume the enums to always have a valid state.

Answer (score 6):

The variable `detection_mode` has type `FileFormatDetection`, so it can
only (legally) contain values in the range 0..2.  Anything else is
undefined behavior.  In your case, apparently, the optmizer is
recognizing this, and suppressing the test for less than zero.

What you should be doing is reading an `int`, and only converting to
`FileFormatDetection` *after* the range check:

```
int raw_detection_mode = ReadIntKey(...);
if ( raw_detection_mode <= 0 || raw_detection_mode > 2 ) {
    raw_detection_mode = Auto;
}
FileFormatDetection detection_mode =
    static_cast<FileFormatDetection>( raw_detection_mode );
```